# Why can I not use this boolean expression in an if clause?

Tags: swift

I have this boolean expression I want to check for in an if statement:

```
var result : NSData? = getResult()
var x : Bool = result == nil
```

This works fine.

```
if x {
}
```

This doesn't work

```
if result == nil {
}
```

It gives me the following errors:

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
Brace block of statements is an unused closure
Expected { after if condition
Invalid character in source file
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `if result == nil { }` does compile (if `result` is an optional). The problem must be in the surrounding context.

Comment: Can you include the declaration of `result` in the question?

Comment: It does not for me! "result" is of type "NSData?"

Comment: unwrapping does not help

Comment: Please give a (minimal) *self-contained* example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I will do so in a moment.

Comment: I created a minimal example and it worked just fine -Then I took a closer look: There were invisible white space characters hidden right next to the if! Maybe I copy pasted them from somewhere online...

Comment: I guess you should take "invalid character in source file" seriously.

Comment: It keeps happening. Invisible evil white space keeps appearing in my code! I really don't know why. It only ever happens when I am creating a new function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were invisible white space characters (characters that take no space) hidden next to the if.